# Error message when importing function - modules

Tags: python, tkinter, module, attributes

I'm building a calculator and I'm in the part of pressing a button and display the value in the screen.  For that purpose, I created two different .py files (I want to use modules). Following up your request I will update the post with the simplest code possible to reproduce the issue. This is the calculator layout:

```
from tkinter import *
from screenvalue import value 

root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root) #frame for the buttons and other options
frame.config(background="#40798C")
frame.pack()
#------------------------ SCREEN ----------------------

screen=Text(frame, width=150, height=5)
screen.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=15)
screen.config(background="#E2E2E2", fg="black")
#--------button---------------------------------

button4=Button(frame, text="4", width=10, padx=0, pady=0, command=value)
button4.grid(row=4,column=11)
root.mainloop()
```

and this is the module I'm using

```
from tkinter import *
character=StringVar()

def value():
    return character.set("4")
```

I changed the name of the module from *typing.py* to *screenvalue.py*. Do you know what's happening? They both are in the same folder

Thank you very much in advance and my apologies if my English is not clear.

Comment: I think you need to add if__name__== main stuff at the end.

Comment: Please post the *complete* exception traceback, and rename your `typing` module to something else - you don't want it to clash with the [`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in the standard library.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it, at the end of what? in the button?

Comment: At this stage, don't worry about `if__name__== main:`. You use that when you have a file that's designed to be used as a stand-alone script and also as an importable module. Right now we just need to see a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: As Aran-Fey said, naming your own module `typing` is not good because it clashes with the standard module of that name. And you definitely shouldn't use `type` as a variable name, because that shadows the built-in `type`, which is the foundation of Python's type system. Using `type` as a variable name makes your code very confusing to read.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the name of the module and I made a simpler code that you can use to replicate the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter is a multilayered thing. Although you're using it from Python, it actually uses another language, Tcl, to manage the GUI.

You get that error message

> ```
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
> ```

because you're trying to create a Tkinter object before you start the Tcl interpreter, which happens when you do `root=Tk()`.

So you need to reorganise your code so that

```
character = StringVar()
```

doesn't get executed before you do `root=Tk()`.

That `character = StringVar()` gets executed when you import `screenvalue`. You *could* just move the import statement after the `root=Tk()`, but it would be much better to change `screenvalue` so that it doesn't run code when you import it.

---

FWIW, `character.set("4")` returns `None`, so there's not much point in having a function return that. Also, there's no point in a callback function returning a useful value, since you can't access the value returned by a callback.

Comment: you are right, my bad. when I was editing this simpler post I deleted command=type within button4 and I forgot to plug it in again. Sorry

Comment: @duvanmendoza No worries. You forgot to change the function name in the module, but I've fixed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `character = StringVar()` outside of the scope of the `type` function that you created and imported in the second file.
In the command `from typing import type` you import only `type` function with its scope and `character` is not defined in it, which causes the error that you got.

If you move `character = StringVar()` into the function's scope it will solve your problem.

`def type():
    character = StringVar()
    return character.set("4")`

P.S it's strongly recommended not to use variable and function names that shadow python built in names, like 'type'.

Comment: Thank you! it solved the issue. Now I have another issue, but I just have to check my code to see what is missing. I wouldn't have figured it out without your help.

Comment: This is completely incorrect and nonsensical. The problem is not related to scope in any way, and moving the `character` variable into the function gets rid of the exception, but it doesn't do anything useful. What's the point of a callback function that creates a StringVar and then does nothing with it?

Comment: This change stops the error message simply because it prevents  `character = StringVar()` from being executed when `screenvalue` is imported. However, creating a new `StringVar` every time the callback is called is probably not a useful thing to do. ;)

Comment: From the original question it seemed that the author needed more clarification regarding scope, lifespan and imports.
That was the point that my answer tried to show and I hope that it moved him one step forward.

I do agree with @PM2Ring that creating a new `StringVar` every time the callback is called is not very useful.